# Can't type password in Git Bash

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I have a strange problem I couldn't find anything about on the web.

I'm learning to use BitBucket and I'm following their walkthrough. I'm using Git Bash as the command prompt as they say [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+Your+Git+Repo+and+Add+Source+Files).

Whenever I need to enter a password, e.g when cloning a repo, it simply refuses to get any input! I type on the keyboard, but nothing is shown on the screen. The only key it does accept is Enter, and then it says authorization fails because there's no password. I can't type it.

The strange thing is that I can type all other commands, just not this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are typing the password, it just does not give you a visible reaction when entering characters (i.e. no `*` symbols). So just type your password correctly, press enter and it should work.

Comment: this is probably the same problem I'm having.

I enter the password, hit return...and it just sits there.  nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can be your problem but first understand that the terminal does let you type your password it just doesn't let you see it for security reasons. Another thing that can fix it is if you are using any numbers in your password try using the keys at the top of the keyboard instead of the keypad. But keep in mind you will not be able to see any of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, GitHub has passwords turned off for command-line and GitHub API. Instead, you are to use a personal access token. You can read more info on how to do that here --> https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

I use bitbucket a great deal. I notice that sometimes when I am cloning a very large repository I enter my password  (which doesn't show) and then I press enter and then I have to wait for quite a while before anything will clone. A slow clone does tend to look like a hang. Try typing in your password, press enter, grab some coffee and come back. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So bit bucket will ask you for the original email password, it will ask you how to manage that input and use whatever. The second time it asks you for a password(the time the characters arent showing in the CMD outlet) it is the app password you set up that is only given at the time of making. go to settings and then app passwords. create and use.